# Deleting the Queue Message is not succeeding after creating the blob using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

This Logic App Requirement is:

1. Get the messages from Azure Storage Queue.
2. For each message, Create a blob in the container using message id.
3. After creating the blob, delete the Queue

[image]
[image]

Every action is working fine, except the 3rd step. Deletion is not working fine.
Where I did wrong?

**Last Action Response**:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "source": "logic-apis-centralus.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "<guidid>",
    "message": "The response is not in a JSON format.",
    "innerError": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Error><Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code><Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.\nRequestId:requid\nTime:2022-12-13T00:30:13.1887047Z</Message><QueryParameterName>popreceipt</QueryParameterName><QueryParameterValue>Queryparametervalue</QueryParameterValue><Reason>Invalid pop receipt format</Reason></Error>"
  }
}
```

Comment: at a guess you aren't providing the proper values in the Delete Message step but you don't show the details of that step.  The error message is pointing to Pop Receipt.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger, Provided the Delete Message Step details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing issue from my side

**The error message is pointing to Pop Receipt  as  Scott Mildenberger said**

Even I got the same **error** because of taking **Message ID as Dynamic content for Pop Receipt**

---

[image]

Got the same error
[image]

**Error resolved from my end after taking Pop Receipt as Dynamic content**

In Delete message action taken Message Id and Pop Receipt as dynamic content as shown in below image
[image]
[image]
After this For each and Delete message actions ran successfully
[image]

**Success code 204**
[image: The error message is pointing to Pop Receipt.]

**Delete message Success Response**

```
{
    "statusCode": 204,
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-request-id": "******",
        "x-ms-client-request-id": "********",
        "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
        "Date": "Wed, 14 Dec 2022 03:04:37 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "0"
    }
}
```

Successfully Queue message deleted as shown in below image
[image]